# Find all combinations of three letters in a list of nine positions

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

i have a list like:

```
['A','B','C']
```

what i want to obtain is all the combinations of these three letters in a nine length list, it can be with repeated letters.

for example:

```
combination_1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A']
combination_2 = ['A','A','A','A','C','A','A','A','A']
combination_3 = ['B','B','B','A','C','A','A','C','C']
```

I would like to do it in python but if there is a solution in other language it will work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combinations with replacement can give it:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

list_ = ["A", "B", "C"]
for comb in combinations_with_replacement(list_, 9):
    print(comb)
```

Prints

```
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C')
....
```

and more :)  (55 in total).

If you want list outputs, you can `print(list(comb))` in the loop above.

(after the comment's correction)

`itertools.product` with `repeat` argument can give it:

```
from itertools import product

list_ = ["A", "B", "C"]
for comb in product(list_, repeat=9):
    print(comb)
```

`3**9 = 19683` items it produces.

Comment: I was writing a basic combination function but oh welp, nice one

Comment: @IşıkKaplan thanks it turns out they already wrote it for us :)

Comment: @FehmiElicebinde I was checking the answer and it gave me 55 combinations, I think there are mucho more combinations, for example the list =[A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C] is not in there and so. do you know how can it be solve?, Thanks!!

Comment: @MarioArango Then you need `itertools.product`. I'm editing the answer i hope it solves it. There are 19683 outcomes! sorry for the first wrong "solution"